# Make BiConsumer accept object

Tags: java

I have a list of column definitions for a JTable TableModel with the column "B" having a setter BiConsumer which accepts a BauwerkOption class and a string.

When I try to set the string in the line with "...accept..." I get following error:

```
The method accept(Selektierung.BauwerkOption, capture#4-of ? extends Object) in the type BiConsumer<Selektierung.BauwerkOption,capture#4-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (Selektierung.BauwerkOption, Object)
```

What is wrong with my code? Is it even possible what I am trying to do?

```
public class TableModelSelektierung extends DefaultTableModel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5921626198599251183L;
    private List<BauwerkOption> data;
    private static List<ColDef<BauwerkOption, ? extends Object>> DEF = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        DEF.add(new ColDef<BauwerkOption, String>("A", (o) -> o.getBauwerkstyp()));
        DEF.add(new ColDef<BauwerkOption, String>("B", (o) -> o.getBezeichnung())
                                                                                            .withSetValueAtFunction((i, o) -> i.setBauwerkstyp(o)));
        DEF.add(new ColDef<BauwerkOption, String>("C", (o) -> o.getNutzungsart()));
        DEF.add(new ColDef<BauwerkOption, Double>("D", (o) -> o.getDurchmesser()));
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return DEF.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return DEF.get(row).getValueSetterFunction() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        if (data != null) {
            return data.size();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        return DEF.get(column).getTitle();
    }

    public void setData(List<BauwerkOption> data) {
        this.data = data;
        fireTableDataChanged();
    }

    public BauwerkOption getObjectAt(int row) {
        return data.get(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
        if (DEF.get(column).getValueSetterFunction() != null) {
            DEF.get(column).getValueSetterFunction().accept(getObjectAt(row), aValue);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int column) {
        BauwerkOption o = getObjectAt(row);
        return DEF.get(column).getValueGetterFunction().apply(o);
    }

}


class ColDef<InputObjekt, OutputValue> {
    private String title;
    private Function<InputObjekt, OutputValue> valueGetterFunction;
    private BiConsumer<InputObjekt, OutputValue> valueSetterFunction;

    public ColDef(String title, Function<InputObjekt, OutputValue> valueGetterFunction) {
        this.title = title;
        this.valueGetterFunction = valueGetterFunction;
    }

    public ColDef<InputObjekt, OutputValue> withSetValueAtFunction(BiConsumer<InputObjekt, OutputValue> valueSetterFunction) {
        this.valueSetterFunction = valueSetterFunction;
        return this;
    }

    public Function<InputObjekt, OutputValue> getValueGetterFunction() {
        return valueGetterFunction;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public BiConsumer<InputObjekt, OutputValue> getValueSetterFunction() {
        return valueSetterFunction;
    }

}

class BauwerkOption {


    public BauwerkOption() {

    }

    public String getBezeichnung() {
        return "";
    }

    public String getBauwerkstyp() {
        return "";
    }

    public Double getDurchmesser() {

        return 0d;
    }

    public String getNutzungsart() {
        return "todo";
    }



    public void setBauwerkstyp(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: I added the BauwerkOption class which I forgot ...

Comment: `BiConsumer<? super InputObjekt, ? super OutputValue> valueSetterFunction` and `withSetValueAtFunction(BiConsumer<? super InputObjekt, ? super OutputValue> valueSetterFunction)`

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @user489872 Thanks for pleasing us (Chris and me) both :-D

Comment: I think this was the best solution :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no clean way of doing this, since the type of the Object parameter in `setValueAt` cannot be changed.

If you replace the following code, it will be as clean as you can get:

This is just for convenience (you don't need own lambdas):

```
private static List<ColDef<BauwerkOption, ?>> DEF = new ArrayList<>();
static {
    DEF.add(new ColDef<BauwerkOption, String>("A", BauwerkOption::getBauwerkstyp));
    DEF.add(new ColDef<BauwerkOption, String>("B", BauwerkOption::getBezeichnung).withSetValueAtFunction(BauwerkOption::setBauwerkstyp));
    DEF.add(new ColDef<BauwerkOption, String>("C", BauwerkOption::getNutzungsart));
    DEF.add(new ColDef<BauwerkOption, Double>("D", BauwerkOption::getDurchmesser));
}
```

In ColDef simply add this method without changing anything else:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public BiConsumer<InputObjekt, Object> getObjectValueSetterFunction() {
    return (BiConsumer<InputObjekt, Object>) valueSetterFunction;
}
```

And then replace setValueAt in TableModelSelektierung with:

```
@Override
public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int row, int column) {
    if (DEF.get(column).getValueSetterFunction() != null) {
        DEF.get(column).getObjectValueSetterFunction().accept(getObjectAt(row), aValue);
    }
}
```

Keeps your generics in place but works around the Object restriction you get from inheriting. You should probably add type checks in setValueAt to make sure the object parameter is of the correct type.

Answer (score 5):

the message

```
The method accept(Selektierung.BauwerkOption, capture#4-of ? extends Object) in the type BiConsumer<Selektierung.BauwerkOption,capture#4-of ? extends Object> is not applicable for the arguments (Selektierung.BauwerkOption, Object)
```

says, that `DEF` is declared as a `list` of `ColDef<BauwerkOption, ? extends Object>` and expects something, that extends an `Object` and not an `Object` itself. so if you remove `? extends` from the declaration of `DEF`, it should work

**Edit**

to be more specific in your code, you could create Value-Object-Classes for `Bauwerkstyp`, `Bezeichnung`, `Nutzungsart`, `Durchmesser`, etc. that extend the Type you want, for example `String` or `Double` and implement an Interface

```
public ColDefStringValue implements IColDefValue<String> {
    @Override
    public String getValue() {
        return ...;
    }
}
```

the interface could look like this

```
public interface ColDefValue<T> {
    T getValue();
}
```

the Interface could be used instead of `? extends Object` or `Object`

```
private static List<ColDef<BauwerkOption, IColDefValue<?>>> DEF = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this just move the problem to another place (the constructor of the ColfDefXXValue classes)?

Comment: perhaps to another place, not necessarily in the constructor. the constructor should look like this `ColDefStringValue(String value)`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `ColDef#getValueSetterFunction()`. This returns a `BiConsumer<BauwerkOption, ?>`, where the question mark refers to some type extending from `Object`. There's no way to know which specific type this is but it is definitely not `Object` itself. Passing a value of type `Object` to the `accept`method in `TableModelSelektierung#setValueAt()` will thus fail with:

```
incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to capture#1 of ?
```

Comment: And there is no workaround? Do I have to pass an Object-Class instead  of the object defined in the ColDef?

Comment: Not really. The gist of the problem is with the `List<ColDef<BauwerkOption, ? extends Object>> DEF`. As Chris' answers says you can switch to `List<ColDef<BauwerkOption, Object>> DEF`, which will shift the error to this list itself. Lists are homogeneous in its type. As soon as you try to work around this you lose type safety in one way or another.